# How iPad Pro Measure App calculate person height?

Tags: swift, ipad, augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit

The new iPad Pro 2020 has a new feature in the Measure application which is displaying the height of the person.

Can anyone know how it is done since the documentation for ARKit 3.5 doesn't have this option?

Answer (score 2):

iPad Pro 2020 equipped with a LiDAR scanner helps a developer construct a topological map of surrounding environment. Also LiDAR scanner greatly improves a quality of ZDepth channel that allows us extract any object located at a definite distance, but also improves People Occlusion, Motion Tracking and Raycasting features. With a LiDAR you can reconstruct a scene even in a badly lit environment.

3d reconstruction of surrounding environment has become possible in ARKit and RealityKit thanks to `sceneReconstruction` instance property. Having a 3d mesh of your scene it's easy to calculate a size of any object using its bounding box (or you can do it using raycasting).

To activate a `sceneReconstruction` option use the following code:

```
let config = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
config.sceneReconstruction = .mesh

arView.debugOptions.insert([.showSceneUnderstanding])
arView.environment.sceneUnderstanding.options.insert([.physics]) 
arView.session.run(config)
```

If you want to know more about bounding box look at [this](https://www.xspdf.com/resolution/20904854.html) and [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnboundingvolume/2034705-boundingbox) articles.